# Deleting/Subsetting Rows in R by setdiff/intersect

Tags: r, intersect, set-difference

I am trying to delete rows out of my data set that contain certain vegetation types. I want to delete the rows from my unsurveyed data that have vegetation types not found in my surveyed data. I found a way to do this but am looking for a one-line method. I am currently doing this:

```
> setdiff(unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION, surveyed_1$VEGETATION)
```

Which returns seven vegetation types that I then delete doing this:

```
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Acer rubrum- Nyssa sylvatica saturated forest alliance",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Acer rubrum/Quercus coccinea-Acer rubrum-Vaccinium corybosum-Vaccinium palladium",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Building",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Parking Lot",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Prunus serotina",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Typha (angustifolia, latifolia) - (Schoenoplectus spp.) Eastern Herbaceous Vegetation",]
> unsurveyed_1 <- unsurveyed_1[!unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION == "Water",]
```

I tried a few different options including subsetting with little success so far figuring that would be my best option. I am also looking to something similar with intersect but am assuming that it would similar answers.

EDIT: 
In addition to using the code that @Cath supplied I edited it to get the opposite as well.

```
> unsurveyed_2 <- unsurveyed_2[unsurveyed_2$VEGETATION %in% setdiff(unsurveyed_2$VEGETATION, surveyed_1$VEGETATION), ]
```

Comment: what about `unsurveyed_1[unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION %in% unique(surveyed_1$VEGETATION), ]` ?

Comment: there is nothing called as `deleting` in data frame in R. Subset it as mentioned by @Cath.

Comment: Thanks @Cath. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious would be to do:

```
ID <- unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION %in% unique(surveyed_1$VEGETATION)
unsurveyed1 <- unsurveyed1[ID,]
```

You use a logical vector `ID` as a row index to select the rows you want to keep. `ID` has a value `TRUE` for every row where `unsurveyed1$VEGETATION` can be found back in `surveyed1$VEGETATION` and `FALSE` otherwise. Using the unique values in `surveyed1$VEGETATION` just increases performance if you have a whole lot of data and not too many different vegetation types.

So there is no need whatsoever to use `setdiff()` and definitely even less need to copy every single result in a new line. Please start thinking in terms of temporary objects when working in R. That'll make your programming life a whole lot easier.

EDIT: This is exactly what @Cath did in his/her comment in a single line.

---

In case you insist on using `setdiff()`, then this would be quite less typing work:

```
thediff <- setdiff(unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION, surveyed_1$VEGETATION)
ID <- unsurveyed_1$VEGETATION %in% thediff
unsurveyed1 <- unsurveyed1[!ID,]
```

Note that you have to invert the `ID` vector using the NOT (`!`) operator to drop all those lines where the unsurveyed vegetation matches a value in `thediff`.

On a sidenote: the internal code of `setdiff()` and `%in%` is almost exactly the same. The difference is that `setdiff()` returns actual values not found in the second vector, and `%in%` returns a logical vector that says `FALSE` if the value wasn't found in the second vector.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't set on using `setdiff()`. I ended up using the one line method @Cath had in their comment. But your explanation of the `%in%` operator was very helpful when I went to subset the opposite as well.

Comment: @Southard  You're welcome. I realized the method Cath gave you, is the exact same as this one. I just make a temporary vector with the IDs, but that's personal style.

Comment: Is it possible to do this based on more than one column?